# Break down this @client.command() snippet

Tags: python, command, client

I am trying to modify the following code but I've come to the conclusion I don't fully understand what is taking place here.
If someone would be so kind as to break it down for me line by line I'd be appreciative.

```
@client.command(name='cmd')
async def cmd(context):
    command = context.message.content.replace("!cmd ", "")
    word_list = command.split()
    if word_list[0] == str(ID):
        word_list.pop(0)
        final_command = " ".join(word_list)
```

Comment: This type of question isn't what Stack Overflow is meant for, and it will probably be downvoted. But I will explain in the comments and hopefully it will help you anyway. [Lines 1-2] These simply create a new command called `cmd`. It runs whenever a discord user sends a message beginning with `!cmd `. [Line 3] This line gets the content of the message that ran the command, which is a string such as `"!cmd ... ..."`. It then removes the start of the string (by replacing it with an empty string). The part it removes is the `!cmd ` because this is not important to what the command should do.

Comment: [Line 4] This line takes the string from the previous line, and turns it into a list of words, using the `.split()` string method. [Line 5] This line checks if the first word of the message is equal to some variable `ID` (which must have been defined somewhere else in the code). This might be done to check that the user running the command has permission to do so - for example, it could be some sort of password. Or it could be for any other reason. The rest of the code in the function will only run if this is true.

Comment: [Line 6] This line removes the first word from the list. Now that the code has checked if the first word is correct, it is no longer important, so it is removed. [Line 7] This line turns the remaining list of words back into a string separated by spaces. It is no longer preceded by `!cmd ` and the first word (the ID, whatever that is) has been removed.

Comment: I appreciate you. I'm newer to python and someone asked me to help incorporate a powershell function I wrote using this as a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
command = context.message.content.replace("!cmd ", "")
```

Removes `!cmd` from the message by replacing it with an empty string

```py
word_list = command.split()
```

Splits the message into a list, each word in the message as an item in the list

```py
if word_list[0] == str(ID):
        word_list.pop(0)
        final_command = " ".join(word_list)
```

If the first word is an ID (`str(ID)` converts the ID to a string it so it can be compared) then remove it from the list. Then combine the words in the list back into a string, joined by spaces.

Comment: I appreciate you. I'm newer to python and someone asked me to help incorporate a powershell function I wrote using this as a template